# GoogleAnalytics iOS SDKをcocoapodで取得した場合のlibAdIdAccess.aはどのようにインストールしたらよいか？

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

GoogleAnalyticsの「ユーザー属性とインタレスト カテゴリに関するレポートの利用」のためIDFA（広告主識別子）を有効にしたいのですが、libAdIdAccess.aがcocoapod経由で取得したGoogleAnalytics内には存在しません。SDKを手動ダウンロードすれば、libAdIdAccess.aのファイルがあるのですが、それをプロジェクトに追加することでよいのでしょうか？

よろしくお願い致します。

Xcode7.1
GoogleAnalytics (3.13.0)
iOS8以上をサポート

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podfileに下記を追加して、`pod install`し直すと入ります。

```
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
```